# Different look and feel based on various geographical locations

Tags: asp.net, .net, themes

I am setting up an ASP .NET website that will serve my local area. Eventually, we hope to expand to other geographical areas. I would like to customize the look and feel based on geographical area. If I log in in Philadelphia, the site will look one way, with Philadelphia relevant data. If I log in in Kentucky, the site will look different, with Kentucky relevant data. But operationally, the site will do the same things in both jurisdictions. So, how to accomplish this? I am thinking Themes for the look and feel part. So, how to implement them? Do I need a separate web site project for each jurisdiction (I would prefer to have one project that served all jurisdictions)? Can I have separate URLs, so that Philadelphia goes to one URL, Kentucky to a different URL, with the Philadelphia URL implementing the Philadelphia theme and the Kentucky URL implementing the Kentucky theme. Do I use a separate master page with each jurisdiction? With the master page implementing the Theme?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do (after detecting the city) is change the class on the body tag:

```
<body class="boston">
```

Then you have an auxillary stylesheet that overrides your default CSS with the changes that are for that particular market. Let CSS do the heavy lifting.

`h1 { .... }` in the standard stylesheet is overridden with:

`.boston h1 { .... }` in the auxilliary CSS

Here is a good example of how swapping stylesheets can dramatically change the way your site looks without changing any of the underlying HTML code.

http://www.csszengarden.com/

Comment: It looks there like the css style is set in a url query ID. Is there a way to make that less visible to the user?

Comment: Yes, you can send the user to a dummy "entry" page with the query ID, set it as a session variable and redirect the user to the real landing page.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, that might be the way to go. So there is a home page for the whole project, the URL would we 'www.home.com' and for each jurisdiction it would be say 'www.home.com/?ID=Philadelphia' or something similar.

Comment: or simply: 'www.home.com/Philadelphia' and use a url-rewrite technique (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2538/URL-Rewriting-with-ASP-NET)